# Add two hashes with same key in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
a = {:start=>"Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:00:00 +0000", :end=>"Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:30:00 +0000", :title=>"2015-01-27T13:00:00+00:00 to 2015-01-27T13:30:00+00:00"}
```

and another hash like

```
b = {:start=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:30:00 +0000, :end=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:00:00 +0000, :title=>"2015-01-27T13:30:00+00:00 to 2015-01-27T14:00:00+00:00"}
```

I want to merge these two into

```
c = {{:start=>"Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:00:00 +0000", :end=>"Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:30:00 +0000", :title=>"2015-01-27T13:00:00+00:00 to 2015-01-27T13:30:00+00:00"},{:start=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 13:30:00 +0000, :end=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:00:00 +0000, title=>"2015-01-27T13:30:00+00:00 to 2015-01-27T14:00:00+00:00"}}
```

I tried the following:

```
c = a.merge(b)
```

and also

```
a.merge!(b)
```

This gave back only one value and

```
c = a+b
```

gave errors.

How to do this?

Comment: Your hash doesn't make sense. It contains a sub-hash not associated with a key?

Comment: @August Yes the hashes don't have a key. I will convert this into json that needs to be in this format for me to work with.

Comment: Well, they _need_ to have a key. Your hash is syntactically incorrect at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its syntactically incorrect even for JSON, I believe. You want an array of hashes, by turning the outer `{}` into `[]`. Better: `c = [a,b].to_json`

Comment: ...And then output `c`.